Which are the most genetically different mammals to humans?
According to this Human and Chimp DNA is 98.8% identical

In terms of actual genes, though, we’re 98.8 percent alike, meaning
only 1.2 percent of our genetic material is not found in chimpanzees.

and according to this,
unequal-nature-geneticists-perspective-human-differences

we share roughly 90 percent of our DNA with mice, dogs, cattle, and
elephants

Even though, this article states
Researchers map genome for cats, dolphins, birds, and dozens of other animals

Mammals, a subset of vertebrates that includes primates, dogs, cats,
mice, and humans, share 50% to 99% of the same DNA and nearly all the
genes from a common ancestor that lived roughly 200 million years ago.

So there are mammals which share much less genes with us than mice, dogs, cattle, and elephants. Which are those mammals who are the most genetically different to humans?

I have replaced your incorrect reference to the genetic code, which you will realize after consulting the Wikipedia page on the topic is identical for all mammals.

google mammal phylogeny

The monotremes (platypus and echidna) are the most genetically distinct mammals from humans. They are also the most genetically distinct mammals from all other non-monotreme mammals. The monotremes are found in the image below on the black line with Ornithorhynchus.
After the monotremes, the marsupials (pink lines) are the next most genetically distinct group from humans (and other placental mammals). Generally, the deeper the divergence between two species in the tree below, the lower the genome similarity between those species (though this might differ a little depending on the exact measure used, see below).

One needs to use caution when comparing statistics about the percent similarity between genomes, as this can be measured in many different ways and is often ambiguous. For example, one statistic might refer to the percent of genes that are shared between species, while another might refer to how similar the sequence is between shared genes.



Species
Gene 1
Gene 2
Gene 3
Gene 4




Blue
ATCG
CCGA
ATTC



Red
ATCC
CAGA

GAGC



In the table above, the blue species shares 66% of its genes with the red species, with those genes being 75% similar in sequence.
Genomes also contain a lot of DNA that is not part of a gene, and similar stretches of DNA can be arranged differently along a chromosome or on different chromosomes. This all means that it's difficult to boil down genome similarity to a single number unless the author is very precise about how they are using the term.
(For what it's worth, 82% of the genes in platypus had readily identified analogs [the technical term is ortholog] in other mammals [opossum, mouse, dog, human] or birds [chicken].)

The image is a work by the OrthoMaM team at the Institute of Evolutionary Sciences of Montpellier (ISEM) and at the University of Montpellier. Original paper: "OrthoMaM: A database of orthologous genomic markers for placental mammal phylogenetics." Ranwez V., Delsuc F., Ranwez S., Belkhir K., Tilak M. & Douzery E. J. P. BMC Evolutionary Biology, 2007, 7:241. CC BY-SA 4.0

This is a really good and challenging question because it involves rare areas of taxonomic controversy.
From the list you present elephants are easily more genetically diverse than an other species in your list. There's nothing controversial about this.
The answer to your question has two different answers regarding the evolution of mammals:

The most ancestral mammalian group are the Xanarthra, according to morphology (older tree "a" in the diagram), so edentates such as armadillos, this also includes anteaters and sloths. Those are the most diverse mammals to humans using the diversity of their phenotypes and traits. Armadillos are very cool BTW.

The most ancestral mammalian group are the Afrotheri , according to phylogenetics (emerging tree "b" in the diagram), so elephants, aardvarks and various shrews.


As this is a question on genetic diversity, rather than the evolution of mammals, then it is without question the Afrotheri, thus the elephants and aardvarks. That is rather surprising (to me), but thats the answer.
HOWEVER the Afrotheri are a big diverse group and I would be really surprised if all their genomes have been sequenced, thus which member of the Afrotheri is more diverse? I very much doubt that can be answered down to the level of a species.
It's one of the few discordant observations between cladists and phylogenetics, usually they are highly congruent approaches: hence it's a good question.
The most basal relative to the mammals are the Monotremata - platypus, i.e. far more genetically diverse, but they are not mammals.

The tree is from the American Museum of Natural History, originally from MS Springer et al. (2004), "Molecules consolidate the placental mammal tree", Trends in Ecology and Evolution 19: 430-438.
I do like controversy, but not in this specific fields of methodology.

@bryanKrause wrote:

Since when is a platypus not a mammal? Also, I do not think you are using the phrase "genetically diverse" with an ordinary meaning.

I am an internationally recognised phylogeneticist - take a look other sites on SE for evidence. Some of the tenants of specific higher and lower eukaryote evolution came from my early work.
Let me answer this is in very simple words:
A PHYLOGENETIC TREE = GENETIC DIVERSITY  .. and that is a very ordinary meaning in biology today (30 years ago maybe it wasn't).
As things evolve the genetic diversity between then increases (except for mammals) and that information is represented in a tree. What is hard to understand about this?
I do question where this criticism of molecular evolutionary theory and its relationship to genetic diversity coming from? Evolution per se has come on significant criticism and molecular evolution was no exception. The majority of those criticisms were not based on empirical science but other principles.
Let me go through the basics:
Criticism 1
Platypus, in a field where the relationship between genetic diversity and evolution is contested - which for placental mammals its nice to have a clear definitive outgroup that is not controversial. It is helpful for technical reasons. If you look at tree a and tree b they are both rooted at the platypus. Why? I clearly stated in the answer that a platypus was not a mammal.
The platypus roots the tree unequivocally and therefore positions the next stage of the controversy, which is the disparity between genetic distance and evolution of the placental mammals. Usually the most evolutionary distant ancestor is the most genetically diverse and that relationship holds across the tree of life. In mammals that is not the case, a basal evolutionary lineage isn't the same as a basal lineage based on genetic diversity.
Criticism 2
GENETIC DIVERSITY I am embarrassed by the second part of the criticism. That is to misunderstand the fundamental tenant of phylogenetics and its relationship to genetic diversity. It is not unordinary but very ordinary.
Phylogenetics is the representation of genetic diversity AS A TREE.
Genetic diversity is quantitated as genetic distance and the relationship between those genetic distances is represented as a tree.  The more basal the branch the more genetically distant the relationship. Thus the most basal (ancestral) branch in the placental mammals is Afrotheri and one of the most recent were humans, i.e. we're at opposite ends of the tree.

THUS if I draw a 1x2 matrix between humans and the other 6400 mammalian species the Afrotheri will collectively show greater genetic diversity than EVERY other species of mammal. Do you see that?
THUS if you do PAIRWISE comparison of genetic diversity for all placental mammals (around 6400 species) and root it at the platypus  distance you will recover tree b. Do you see that?

Thus every member of the Afrotheri is more genetically diverse against humans than any other species of placental mammal alive today AND THAT IS WHAT TREE B represents. I do repeat that this is old science.

I've worked with marsupials and even at publication level "mammals" are shorthand for "placental mammals", i.e. distinguishing them from marsupials, and everyone understands that. Technically marsupials are mammals but a different order, in the same way Monotremata are the order for platypus. "Mammals" is shorthand for the Order of placental mammals, their Linnaean taxonomy is rarely used.

More comments: there is a technical gulf here about how concepts are worded and how they are interpreted, leave it at that.

I started to wonder this because, doesnt seem odd that there are non mammals  (like white sharks) which share more DNA with humans (65%) than other mammals (50%)?

@Pablo I'd suggest this is not a like for like comparison in this specific case, however ichthyology (fish) is outside my expertise. For example, one might DNA diversity the other might be protein diversity, or nuclear genome and the other mitochondrial genome.

Since when is a platypus not a mammal? Also, I do not think you are using the phrase "genetically diverse" with an ordinary meaning.

@Pablo This confusion comes up a lot. There is no single type of "percent shared" that makes sense for this sort of measurement, and it gets less and less sensible the less related the species are. If you're comparing numbers you better make sure they're the same sort of number.

@BryanKrause is categorization of living organisms changing based on DNA? I understand traditionally  taxonomists categorized living organisms based on morphology and physical traits, and that is still being used today

@BryanKrause I have responded to your question in detail

Perhaps there is some debate in your community I am not aware of, but my understanding is that a platypus is in fact a mammal, albeit a quite unusual one compared to species most familiar to humans. By what criteria are you determining that it is not?

The platypus are not placentals (they lay eggs) and all the examples in the question were placentals. Had the OP said "kangaroos" that would be different - they didn't.

The question said "mammals"; your answer says "mammals".

Did you really expect the OP to say the most genetically diverse Eutheria and do you refer to yourself as a member of the Eutheria? No! The examples were all Eutheria and commonly referred to as mammals.

No, but they said mammals as did you and neither you nor they specified "placental mammals" until now. Mammals are mammals. Placental mammals are placental mammals. OP did not ask "of mice, dogs, cattle, and elephants, which are most genetically different from humans?" - they acknowledged that there are mammals more different than the ones in their list and asked which those would be.

As far as genetic diversity, I cannot find a source that is consistent with your usage where you say things like "elephants are easily more genetically diverse than an other species in your list." This statement would seem to indicate more genetic variability among elephants, rather than distance between elephants and some other species. Genetic diversity is a population measure, describing either variation within a species or describing a population of species as in ecology. Genetic diversity is a measure of dispersion, not of distance.

For another example: This usage makes sense to me: "HOWEVER the Afrotheri are a big diverse group" - you are describing variation within a group, saying there is a high dispersion there. But: "which member of the Afrotheri is more diverse?" does not really make sense. You could maybe describe Afrotheri as more diverse than some other group; it would certainly be more diverse than any subgroup it contains, but an individual species cannot be diverse or more diverse unless you're describing variation within that species, which is not the meaning used in context.

@Pablo The gold standard these days for categorization is based on DNA, yes, but not necessarily by "similarity". Rather, since we understand generally how changes to the DNA occur (whether at a single base or larger level), it's possible to make inferences about shared ancestry based on changes that are shared or not shared by different relatives. You can't really do it with just two species, you need to take a more wholistic view. As M__ mentions, often this involves use of an outgroup to infer the ancestral state.

@BryanKrause thanks for the discussion but there is a significant technical gulf between us on taxonomy and population science, and leave it at that: the technical way concepts are worded is part the issue.

Can you give an example of the use of "genetic diversity" to mean "genetic distance" in taxonomy?

Look this is the last post, you are simply in error. "Genetic diversity" isn't the singular domain of population genetics and population genetics is first and foremost about allele frequency usually within a species complex. What you appear to be arguing is allele frequency is a singular function of genetic diversity and it isn't. This discussion is the genetics between species complexes. E.g. Nei's genetic diversity is a formal quantity based on allele frequency, but genetic diversity has a bigger context.

No, that is not my argument. My argument is that if you mean to say that two species are more genetically different, you should say they are different or distant, not "diverse". If you want to say that a group of species have lots of distance among them, you could describe them as "genetically diverse" just like you would individuals of a population. It does not make sense to write "elephants are easily more genetically diverse" in the context you have. You might say it if you meant to say a species of elephant has a lot of diversity or there is a lot of diversity between elephant species.

In phylogenetics, genetic distance is the quantitation of genetic diversity by modelling point mutations.

Do you mean the quantitation of genetic divergence?

The term "genetic divergence" (whatever that means) was not used at any point. This is increasingly looking like I am been trolled by a mod I have to politely ask you to desist.

I didn't say it was used, I am saying it is the correct phrase to use, instead of the one you are using, unless you're able to point me to some source to indicate that it is actually used in the field you claim to be from in the way you claim it is used. I understand that it feels like I'm being unnecessarily pedantic about this, but I think you are using terminology in quite an unusual way which is confusing for people trying to learn biology.

This is increasingly a troll, I don't teach undergraduate - but I wouldn't expect this kind of behaviour at that level. I am politely asking you to desist.

I guess I'll settle for Wikipedia references, I thought doing so might be seen as condescending, but if you're not familiar with the terms maybe it would help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_divergence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_diversity

Here's the Frontiers definition - kids version https://kids.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/frym.2021.656168 . I didn't want to be condescending either. Frontiers has an impact factor

That source is using the diversity among a group of species definition, which I have referred to in each of my comments. It is not the way you are using the term incorrectly, which is to instead describe the distance/divergence between two species. You are using the wrong word.

We've been through this already - using allele frequency as the sole definition of genetic diversity and thats what you are saying ... and thats wrong

You've said that before, but I am not using allele frequency as the sole definition of genetic diversity.

Yes you are because the Wiki source is based on allele frequency calculations, as soon as you attempt to wrap numbers on the diversity - it's all allele frequencies. So whether it's a haplotype map, F-stasticics, HW, Nei's etc .... it's the frequency of allele they measure. Phylogenetics isn't based on allele frequency

I've several times acknowledged that genetic diversity is also used in e.g. ecology to describe dispersion in populations of species, not only for allele frequencies within species. What I have said several times is that it is not appropriate to say "elephants are easily more genetically diverse than an other species" when what you mean is "elephants are more genetically different/diverged/distance from humans". I have never said phylogenetics is based on allele frequency but thank you for the attempt to educate.

I've got to agree with @Bryan-Krause. It is simply incorrect to say, "elephants are easily more genetically diverse than an other species in your list," and intend to communicate that the genomes of elephants differ the most from humans compared to the other species. What that phrase does communicate is that, if one were to measure genetic diversity within elephants, and within humans, and within mice, etc., then the diversity measured within elephants is the highest.

Yes, one can talk about genetic diversity across species, and use a phylogeny to express that. That would be relevant for a sentence like, "Wow, there's a lot of diversity within this clade" (where the clade could be the whole phylogeny). But it's the wrong vocabulary to point to two taxa split deep in the tree and say that "these two are the most genetically diverse." As noted, one could say they are the most genetically divergent, or different, or distinct.

Yeah I accept that that specific phrase needs tightening (minor point), because it would get confused for infra-species diversity which wasn't its intention. The days when terminology from the English language was restricted to equations by Masatoshi Nei (who just died), are over.
